# TRUNCATE whole table if TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD')='01' in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a large set of records (**1.2m+ records**) in a table, where everyday records are being inserted/updated accordingly.

Now, I got a new business requirement.

*The requirement is as below,*

> IF CURRENT_DAY is 01, i.e., each and every 1st day of the month, the
>   table will be TRUNCATED, if not, then the regular insert/update job
>   will continue.

I've solved in from INFORMATICA ETL's end, the logic is as below,

```
SQ: SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE 1=2
```

i.e., There aren't any source records

```
SQ > EXP > NEW OUTPUT PORT > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD') - CURR_DAY
```

Now,

```
EXP > RTR > NEW GROUP > CURR_DAY = '01'
```

Then,

```
RTR > NEW GROUP > TGT > SESSION PROPERTIES > ENABLED TRUNCATE
```

In this way, the requirement is fulfilled.

**But, I want to know if there's any other way to achieve this using ONLY PURE PL/SQL or SQL?**

Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PL/SQL` as follows:

```
BEGIN
IF TRUNC(SYSDATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MON') THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE';
END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Decision Task` to check if it's the first day of a month. If it is, run a dummy session with a `truncate target table` option enabled and some dummy query on SQ (like `select 1 from dual where 1=2`. Next, connect it to your regular dataload session.
Connect the `Decision` to the same regular dataload session with a `False` condition also, to make it run directly if it's not 1st day of a month.

```
Start --> Decision (is 1st?) ---yes---> s_trunc
                            \                  \
                             \------no--------> s_regular_load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the table in two ways. You can use pre query to delete the tables using below condition.

```
delete from table where to_char(sysdate, 'DD') = '01'; -- You can also use required date instead of sysdate
```

Or you can create a procedure to truncate table with same condition